# ASP.NET5 MVC6 rc2-16317 LOCALISATION

Tags: localization, asp.net-core

I'm ASP.NET5 MVC6 rc2-16317 - visual studio 2015 business
and my question concerns the location with the resx file.
I followed most of the tutorials but its still not working.
Thank you

At startup.cs (ConfigureServices):

```
 services.AddLocalization();  
 services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
 services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizerFactory, TestStringLocalizerFactory>();
```

At startup.cs (Configure):

```
var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {

            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo("fr-FR")),

            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                new CultureInfo("en-US")
            },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                 new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                new CultureInfo("en-US")
            }
        };
app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions );

app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseIdentity();

app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

At AccountController:

```
private readonly IHtmlLocalizer _htmlLocalizer;


    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;


    public AccountController(IHtmlLocalizer<AccountController> htmlLocalizer, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _htmlLocalizer = htmlLocalizer;

        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }


    public IActionResult Login()
    {

        ViewBag.Tests = _htmlLocalizer["Learn More"]; // _htmlLocalizer["Aujourd'hui c'est le: {0}", DateTime.Now];
        //return View("Login", _htmlLocalizer["Connectez-vous<small> dès maintenant!</small>"]);
       return View();
    }
```

Hello thank you for your reply;
I close this question because I already resolved my problem by the use of JsonConfigurationStringLocalizer.

Thank you.

Comment: can u share your code ?

Comment: Hello thanks you for your answer i have just edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace
`services.AddLocalization();`
with
`services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "<pathToResourceFiles>");`

More info here: http://damienbod.com/2015/10/21/asp-net-5-mvc-6-localization/